# Core competency or core competence?

Tags: word-usage, nouns, word-difference, suffixes

I've used an expression "core competency" for years and recently found out that it is correct to say "core competence", as in "growing vegetables is my core competence". Now I'm in doubt so I'm asking here. What is the right way to say about what I'm most competent at?

Comment: Can you also add a phrase using "core competency", for comparison purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both words are in the OED, with almost identical definitions (except that *competence* has a couple of specialised meanings that *competency* hasn't).

An [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=competence%2Ccompetency&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccompetence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccompetency%3B%2Cc0) of the words shows that *competency* was slightly more common than *competence* until about 1890, but after 1920 the prevalence of *competence* rose rapidly: today it is about six times as common in books as *competency*.

An [ngram of the phrases](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=core%20competence%2Ccore%20competency&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccore%20competence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccore%20competency%3B%2Cc0) shows that *core competence/competency* were almost unknown until 1990, since when they have both risen rapidly, with *core competence* about 50% more common than *core competency*.

On the other hand, GloWbE (the corpus of Global Web-based English) has *core competenc**y*** more common than *core competenc**e*** (40 instances against 27); but *competence* three and a half times as common as *competency* (6840 against 1987).

So, both are acceptable, in general *competence* is rather more common than *competency*, but in the comparatively small number with *core*, the different corpora disagree as to which is more common.